# How to backup 2FA Google Authenticator

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I'm using Google Authenticator for 2FA (2-factor-authentication) on several sites. Now what if I lose my Iphone? Than they're gone.

Is there a save way to backup 2FA? I read about [authy](https://authy.com/) but it seems to me you lose the point of 2FA when you use it? + what if it's hacked? Another option I thought about was to disable 2FA, and reenable it. Take a real picture of the QR code and scanning it afterwards to reenable. But I'm not sure if that way will work?

Comment: Backup the secret code and the image QR code you scanned.  You can restore the authenicator using one of those, if you have neither, then the authenticator CANNOT be recovered.

Comment: Each and every site that implements this correctly provides you with a number of backup/recovery codes that can be used once, in place of a code from the app.

Comment: Yep, looked over it. Disabling, writing code and reenabling did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google allows you to do various things for these 'what if' situations.

One thing it will of prompted you to do is download and print/make a copy of some codes to use in emergencies such as losing your phone. You can also set up/request they call you/send a SMS when you don't have a code, and so if you got your phone replaced you'd still receive these.

Also, normally the authentication isn't every single time, it's only every 30 days or so (depending on settings and the service) and so you can normally return to a machine you're already authorised on and access your account this way.